# Update Text File with Form Without PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I need to create a form that will allow users to update a simple text file and then be able to save it in the same location on the server. I can't use PHP (company policy). Is there any way to do this with client-side scripting? My server side scripting is severely restricted. To clarify I just need the contents of an "alert.txt" file to be updated by a user form.

```html
   <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="alert">Post an Alert</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alert" placeholder="Enter alert here">
      </div>
      
      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You'll need to use a server-side language to process the data and write on the server, otherwise your server files would be accessible by absolutely anyone, which is a critical security issue. Does you company use any other back-end language?

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure I can use ASP or maybe even JSP.

Comment: Also, we are using a SharePoint to host this Single Page App. So access to the form itself would be permission based.

Comment: You could try to add an `action="my_asp_page.aspx"` attribute to your `form` element (along with a `method="POST"` attribute) and write to the text file using ASP (or even using JSP if you want to).